# Problem with accessing FirebaseDatabase in Android Studio after a successfull initialization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, i've been trying to set up a FirebaseDatabase in android studio. I followed the steps in the documentation and it now tells me `I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful`.

The issue that i have, is that if i'm calling `setValue()` or actually all kinds of methods that get or set values in the database, it doesn't do anything. I even put a Success and Failure Listener on it and it calls none of them. The app doesn't crash and also prints no error.

I've tried so many things now, watched every tutorial, read so many posts and still don't make any progress. I really need to get this done, but i'm so clueless :/
Things that i did so far:

- Add Internet permission to manifest
- Tried different versions of the dependencies
- Debugging the code:
  This gives me the right URL, but slightly different to the one i see in the Firebase Console. In the Firebase Console the URL is
  `https://xxxxxxxxx-daf04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/` and the one that i get as reference inAndroid Studio is `https://xxxxxxxxx-daf04-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/scores`
- Set Write and Read permission to `true`
- Many more things

This is basicly all the code thats called after pressing a button:

```
FirebaseDatabase fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = fb.getReference("scores");
reference.setValue("Test")
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Write was successful!
                System.out.println("Entry successfull");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                System.out.println("Entry failed!");
            }
        });
```

App-Level Gradle File:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Gradle File:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

...
```

Comment: try this 

getReference().child("scores").setValue()

Comment: I tried that before, but it doesn't change anyting :/

Comment: is firebase showing your app that you connect?

Comment: Where can i see that? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you try explicitly specifying the URL in your Java code with: `FirebaseDatabase fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference()`? It shouldn't be needed, but some devs have had issue with that before.

Comment: Frank ... you are a frickin legend. it worked :)

Comment: Hmmm.... believe it or not, but I'm not too happy about that. I've been unable to reproduce this problem myself, so can't file a bug for it. If the URL exists in the `google-services.json`, the SDK should pick it up from there (as its the default database for the project). Can you open the `google-services.json` from your disk, and double check if the database URL is in there?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer. I checked the `google-services.json`, but it looks as expected. The exact same URL as the one that i now used in my `getInstance()`.